# How do I fix a testing issue in Swift when I forget to set a delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, delegates, nsoperation

Background: I'm learning Swift and TDD simultaneously for self improvement purposes and to try to keep up with current tech. This issue, I'm not calling it a bug, made me scratch my head for a while. It centers around an XML parsing operation passing a test when it shouldn't because a delegate was not set, and thus does not work.

Here are the classes of interest:

```
class ParseOperation: NSOperation, NSXMLParserDelegate {
    private var parser: NSXMLParser?
    var dataToParse: NSData?

    private var parseResults: AnyObject?
    private var parseError: NSError?

    override func main() {
        if let data = dataToParse {
            parser = NSXMLParser(data: data)

            // neglecting to set the delegate of the parser as self does not cause the test to fail
            // parser?.delegate = self

            parser?.parse()
        }
    }

    func getParseResults() -> AnyObject? { return parseResults }
    func getParseError() -> NSError? { return parseError }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        // do parsing stuff
        parseResults = NSObject()
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
        self.parseError = parseError
    }
}
```

Here I have a minimal parsing setup for XML. By neglecting to set the parser's delegate none of the NSXMLParseDelegate will be called.

```
class Manager: NSObject {
   func parseSomeXMLInAQueue(completion:(results: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
       let operation: ParseOperation = {
           var tempParseOp = ParseOperation()
           tempParseOp.dataToParse = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><a/>".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
           tempParseOp.completionBlock = {
               completion(results: tempParseOp.getParseResults(), error: tempParseOp.getParseError())
           }
           tempParseOp.qualityOfService = .UserInitiated
           tempParseOp.queuePriority = .Normal

           return tempParseOp
       }()

       let queue = NSOperationQueue()
       queue.addOperation(operation)
   }
}
```

A manager class that creates a parse operation and tosses it into a queue to run on another thread.

```
class Test: XCTestCase {
   func testParserParsesGoodXMLData() {
       let expectation = expectationWithDescription("parser should execute closure")

       let manager = Manager()
       manager.parseSomeXMLInAQueue { results, error in
           // so, the block is called, fulfill the expection immediately so we don't timeout
           expectation?.fulfill()

           if let someError = error {
               XCTFail("Got an error")
           }

           // now test that our parsing was successful
           XCTAssertNotNil(results, "Should get some object from parser")
       }

       waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(1, handler: nil)
   }
}
```

And, this test should fail due to the results object being nil, but it succeeds for some reason.

Setting a breakpoint on XCTAssertNotNil causes all sorts of interesting results. First, continuing after the breakpoint is hit gives a SIGABRT signal. Then, continuing again steps back to our thread and gives the test a pass. What gives?